# Is it advisable to run Couchbase with 'EFS Elastic Throughput' instead of EBS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, couchbase

We run Couchbase in Kubernetes platform in AWS cloud. As per the 'Couchbase on AWS' best practices, it is suggested to use EBS 'gp3' or EBS 'io1' based on the following link. (https://docs.couchbase.com/server/current/cloud/couchbase-cloud-deployment.html#aws-deployment-methods)

But it seems AWS has introduced a new EFS storage type, known as, "Amazon EFS Elastic Throughput" (https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/new-announcing-amazon-efs-elastic-throughput/). It gives much better throughput. Is it suggested to use EFS with Elastic Throughput for Couchbase storage?

*Throughput claimed by AWS: Elastic Throughput allows you to drive throughput up to a limit of 3 GiB/s for read operations and 1 GiB/s for write operations per file system in all Regions.*

Answer (score 1):

Apologies for the delay here.  In short, no we do not recommend using EFS with Couchbase as it is a file share rather than a block device.